# Scroll aware FAB hides, but then does not reappear

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made an Android app with a `recyclerview` and a `floating action button`. When scrolling down, the button should hide, when scrolling up it should show again. I have used [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons) to implement the behavior.

The result is, that the FAB hides when I scroll down, but when scrolling up it does not reappear again :( The class `ScrollAwareFABBehavior` is identical from the tutorial. But I'm using nested layouts.

Here is my layout (the `recyclerview` is in a `LinearLayout` in `content_main`):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="org.myorganisation.mypackage.someActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        app:layout_behavior="org.myorganisation.mypackage.someActivity.helpers.ScrollAwareFABBehavior" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/insert_alert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingEnd="70sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/add_fab"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/initial_alert"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24sp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 25.1.0 of the Support Library, hidden views no longer scroll events as per [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230298).

As mentioned in [comment #5](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230298#c5):

> This is working as intended, your dependency chain is the wrong way. Your RecyclerView (Behavior) should be triggering the FAB visibility change.

Comment: You can also switch to the approach recommended by the bug - there's an example [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/compare/master...ianhanniballake:scroll_aware_fab)

Comment: @ianhanniballake the new solution has a problem, it does not hide the fab if the list fills the viewport. Although this probably is desired because the fab may overlay the last item in the list. Any ideas how to solve that? I want to avoid adding a bottom padding to my list just to be able to scroll the content above the fab in this case...

Comment: No need to change your dependency chain - the solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082313/1112963

Comment: Just because you found a workaround to keep doing it wrong does not make it right

Comment: @ianhanniballake True words! But I needed a quick fix first to get the time to make it right ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As for support library version `25.1.0`, the **solution** is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761736/android-design-library-25-1-0-causes-floatingactionbutton-behavior-to-stop-worki/42082313#42082313).

Answer (score 3):

**Here is simple solution:**

The concept behind this is very simple, you just need to detect when user scrolls down and up the RecyclerView. In Android there are some built in methods that can help us detect when user is scrolling either side in Recyclerview. See the code below, since it will show the full concept:

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

       rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
          @Override
          public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
          }

          @Override
          public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

              if (dy < 0) {
                  fab.show();

               } else if (dy > 0) {
                  fab.hide();
               }
         }
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by replacing 
.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) with .show(true) and 
.setVisibility(View.GONE) with .hide(true):

And here is my class for the Behaviour, that works with 25.1.0: and [Clans FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton)

```
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {
private static boolean mIsAnimatingOut = false;
private static final Interpolator INTERPOLATOR = new FastOutSlowInInterpolator();

public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super();
}

@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fabButton, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
}

@Override
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton fabButton, View dependency) {
    float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
    fabButton.setTranslationY(translationY);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                                   FloatingActionButton fabButton, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL ||
            super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, fabButton, directTargetChild, target,
                    nestedScrollAxes);

}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton fabButton,
                           View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, fabButton, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
            dyUnconsumed);

    if (fabButton.isEnabled()) {
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && !mIsAnimatingOut && fabButton.isShown()) {
            animateOut(fabButton);
        } else if ((dyConsumed < 0 || dyUnconsumed < 0) && fabButton.isHidden()) {
            animateIn(fabButton);
        }
    }
}

public static void animateOut(final FloatingActionButton fabButton) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        ViewCompat.animate(fabButton).translationY(168F).alpha(0.0F).setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR).withLayer()
                .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListener() {
                    public void onAnimationStart(View view) {
                        mIsAnimatingOut = true;
                    }

                    public void onAnimationCancel(View view) {
                        mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                    }

                    public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                        mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                        fabButton.hide(true);
                    }
                }).start();
    } else {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(fabButton.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
        anim.setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR);
        anim.setDuration(200L);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                mIsAnimatingOut = true;
            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                fabButton.hide(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation animation) {
            }
        });
        fabButton.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}

public static void animateIn(FloatingActionButton fabButton) {
    fabButton.show(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        ViewCompat.animate(fabButton).translationY(0).scaleX(1.0F).scaleY(1.0F).alpha(1.0F)
                .setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR).withLayer().setListener(null)
                .start();
    } else {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(fabButton.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
        anim.setDuration(200L);
        anim.setInterpolator(INTERPOLATOR);
        fabButton.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

}