# onNestedScroll called only once

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I have a class

```
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final FloatingActionButton child,final View directTargetChild, final View target, final int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, final FloatingActionButton child,final View target, final int dxConsumed, final int dyConsumed,final int dxUnconsumed, final int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            child.hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            child.show();
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that onNestedScroll is called only once when I scroll up a recyclerview, so the fab is hiding and never shows again. Here is layout I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            app:layoutManager="@string/vertical_linear_layout_manager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="mypackagename.util.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_margin="16sp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My support libraries version is 25.1.0

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the visibility from GONE to INVISIBLE with the following code.

```
 @Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child,
                           View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed,
            dyUnconsumed);

    if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        child.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShown(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                super.onShown(fab);
            }

            @Override
            public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                super.onHidden(fab);
                fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    } else if (dyConsumed <= 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        child.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kit if the view is `GONE` it's no longer considered part of the layout and therefore that view's `LayoutBehavior` would not be called. When a view is `INVISIBLE` it's part of the layout but not visible.

Comment: You saved my hours. Thanks

Comment: Thanks...I use child.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); to fix it. But thanks to you I knew what to fix.

Answer (score 5):

I have just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41811364/6583492) 
to absolutely the same problem in another post, check it.

Speaking shortly, use the following:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

Comment: For the record, I recently tried to switch to `com.android.support:design:25.2.0` and this behaviour is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type) {
    super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type);
    if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        child.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                super.onHidden(fab);
                fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        child.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is better than Eduardo's answer (less code).
The condition (`child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE`) is also useless. I use support lib v27.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the visibility of FAB to GONE in child.hide() - use INVISIBLE instead. From 25.1.0, the scroll events are not passed on to views whose visibility is GONE

Comment: but .hide() is implemented inside the support library

Answer (score 0):

For me i replace child.hide() with ((View)child).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE).